# Can javapackager package Windows app from a Mac?

Tags: java, javapackager

Can javapackager (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719) package Windows app from a Mac, or does one need to actually install Windows?

Comment: You could run javapackager using Wine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle docs:

> Self-contained application packages are platform-specific and can only
>   be produced for the same system on which you build. To deliver
>   self-contained application packages on Windows, Linux, and OS X, you
>   must build your project on all three platforms.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#A1307236